# handling player impact in a proper way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

hi i have a quite a complicated question for me at least .
in my player controller class i use unity's characterController component
to move the player based of the input i give it to it
and multiply it with speed and add the gravity like this

```
        CurrentImpact = vector3.lerp(CurrentImpact,vector3.zero, damping * Time.DeltaTime) 
        velocity = InputDirection();
        velocity *= Speed();
        velocity += Gravity;
        velocity += CurrentImpact;
        CharcerController.move(velocity  * Time.deltatime)
```

my problem is with CurrentImpact.
CurrentImpact is a vector3 that i use to add force to the player like jumping and pushing the player around
put if i do like adding a force facing left maybe and the player is trying to move right, the player will go right then will start drifting a little bit on the left again
so what i think i want is a way to make the CurrentImpact Face the direction of the input movement if its weaker than it without changing its magnitude.

i hope you understand me and thanks

Answer (score 0):

> what think i want is a way to make the CurrentImpact Face the direction of the input movement if its weaker than it without changing its magnitude.

Not sure if it solves your actual problem but I think you could do that by using something like

```
CurrentImpact = vector3.lerp(CurrentImpact, vector3.zero, damping * Time.DeltaTime);
var inputDirection = InputDirection();
var speed = Speed();

velocity = inputDirection * speed;

var impactMagnitude = CurrentImpact.magnitude;

// Check if your impact is weaker then the movement (without gravity I guess - otherwise do it after adding it)
if(impactMagnitude < speed)
{
    CurrentImpact = inputDirection * impactMagnitude;
}

velocity += Gravity;
velocity += CurrentImpact;
CharcerController.move(velocity  * Time.deltatime);
```

Comment: @TMoaw Well yes ... what you said in `so what i think i want is a way to make the CurrentImpact Face the direction of the input movement if its weaker than it without changing its magnitude` sounds exactly like that is what you wanted

Comment: thanks for your efforts, but the problem now is that i get extra force towards the input direction because of the input direction itself and the CurrentImpact. this is happening in the first solution the second one i didn't really like because it had the same problem like the first one but instead of only making the player faster like the first solution it made the whole velocity stronger so stronger gravity and faster movement etc

Comment: sorry i deleted the reply as fast as possible because i couldn't finish it without hitting enter accidently